# Google BigQuery API get state of running job non-US location in Clojure

Tags: clojure, google-bigquery

I have an app that reads CSV files and pushes it to BQ tables, checks for the status of that job before doing the next CSV file and so on. This was working fine while my datasets were in the US region, however we recently moved our datasets to Australia region and now I get

`#error { :cause 404 Not Found { "code" : 404, "errors" : [ { "domain" : "global", "message" : "Not found: Job load-csv-job123", "reason" : "notFound" }`

While I can run the job fine against this dataset but I cannot call the BQ get API in my Clojure code to get the status. While calling the insert job API I am setting the location in the jobReference

`job-reference (doto (JobReference.) (.setLocation "australia-southeast1") (.setJobId job-id) )`
and then call my insert like this

```
 status (->> bq
                    (.jobs)
                    (#(.insert % project-id job-spec content))
                    (.execute)
                    (.getStatus))]
```

The status above works when I do `(->> status (.getState)`

I know I have to be setting the location somewhere for non-US/non-EU regions for the GET call on the job, but just can't figure how to from the Google Docs using the GET API.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/get

The API/jar I am using in the below code

[com.google.apis/google-api-services-bigquery "v2-rev459-1.25.0"]

The code I have for getting status in a loop with recur

```
(loop [status status]                                   ;; Waiting until successfully processed
      (log/info job-id " : " (->> status (.getState)))
      (if (= "DONE" (->> status (.getState)))
        (do (log/info "Status seems done?")
          (if-let [errors (.getErrors status)]
            (do
              (log/info "seems like we have errors")
              (vec (map #(.getMessage %) errors)))
            nil))
        (do
          (log/info "status is pending let's wait and check...job spec" job-spec)
          (Thread/sleep 3000)

          (recur (->> bq
                      (.jobs)
                      (#(.get % project-id job-id))
                      (.execute)
                      (.getStatus))
                 ))))))
```

Can you tell what I am missing, my attempts to setLocation on the .get
`(#(.get % project-id job-id))(.setLocation "australia-southeast1")`
comes back with

````
CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching field found: setLocation for class java.lang.String, compiling:```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out the Clojure code for how to set location when dataset has moved from one region to another, this is need to get the status of the jobs that are already run. Note that I had to make sure in my case that the previous BQ job(insert into table) has finished before I run the next one. I loop through the status and recur on it till I get a DONE. Note that DONE here doesn't mean success of the job, just that the job has finished. Which is why I fetch the err vec below if there were any errors and return that.

I was using a threaded form `->>` for this initially but couldnt figure how to setLocation that way, so used a plain form now. I will update with a threaded form later.

```
(loop [status status]                                   ;; Waiting until successfully processed
      (log/info job-id " : " (->> status (.getState)))
      (if (= "DONE" (->> status (.getState)))
        (do (if-let [errors (.getErrors status)]
              (do
                (log/debug "Errors in job: " job-id)
                (vec (map #(.getMessage %) errors)))
              nil))
        (do
          (Thread/sleep 3000)
          (recur
            (let [jobsobj (.jobs bq)
                  
                  getobj (.get jobsobj project-id job-id)
                  _ (.setLocation getobj "australia-southeast1")
                  ]
               (.getStatus (.execute getobj)))
            ))))
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing that's missing here appears to be the details about which clojure library you're using.  That's not a language supported by first party libraries, so this may come down to how the library is assembled, and whether it's maintained.

For a jobs get call, the thing that's needed is for the request to route correctly is to add a `location` URL param to the request, e.g. `GET https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/yourprojectid/jobs/yourjobid?location=australia-southeast1`

Comment: Yes, I am using the [com.google.apis/google-api-services-bigquery "v2-rev459-1.25.0"] API /library. I am looking for code that can help me set location on the ->> call the .get

Comment: I don't know how it manifests in clojure, but in java it's `setLocation()` on the jobs get call: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/bigquery/Bigquery.Jobs.Get.html

Comment: Thx for the pointers, yes I had come upon that API doc however needed something in Clojure for this.